# Syntax error for overloading generic arrow function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, arrow-functions

```
interface Foo1 {
  (param: number): number
  (param: string): string
}

const foo1: Foo1 = (param: number | string) => param as any
const foo2 = <T>(param: T) : T => param 

interface Foo3<T1, T2> {
  (param: T1): T1
  (param: T2): T2
}

const foo3: Foo3<T1, T2> = <T1, T2>(param: T1 | T2) => param as any
// [ts] Cannot find name 'T1'. [2304]
// [ts] Cannot find name 'T2'. [2304]
```

I have searched on StackOverflow but questions only talk about either of them or did not answered the question.

Comment: You're not overloading a function; you are declaring a function. You will need to provide the generic type arguments (T1 and T2). What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I am trying to return different types based on the parameter types.

Comment: You have to indicate what `T1` and `T2` are, but I don't think you need both generics. It seems like just one would be fine like you have for `foo2`

Comment: @ExplosionPills The second one won't work because what I am trying to do is the `param` is fixed type but the return value is generic type.

Comment: interface Foo3 is generic interface with no default generic type. so when u try to initialize foo3 you have to set these generic types. you can not create const foo3: Foo3<T1, T2>... here you have to say what these generic values are

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
interface Foo {
  <T1 extends number>(param: T1): T1;
  <T2 extends string>(param: T2): T2;
}

const foo: Foo = <T1, T2>(param: T1 | T2) => param;

let numberResult = foo(1); // result is 1
let stringResult = foo("test") // result is "test"
let errorResult = foo({test:"hello"}) //error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIA8AKgIzIQAekIAJgM7IgCuAtgEbQB8AFAA5wocVgC5kZAJRiyAbnxFiAJgrUIdRvTBRQAc14Cho8YqnG5AX1y4E6EJuQxMYjFgC8C0gBpj+wcOnkAD7GEsiuXMgGwnK4ADYQYExsnFAAShD0zLGJ7o7oPKQScvGJmtogOumZ2WEOmDwARJCaDRJxCRRQUOhpGVk5dfnYzWAiDQAWELGx6A3mbUA)